# Alternatives to the median filter

Tags: filters, frequency, median-filter

I have a embedded system where I get some type of sensor readings with varying frequency between 0.3 to 1 Hz. Sometimes these readings may have impulse like noise. To filter out this noise, I've implemented a median filter with total 3 data points. Since noisy values does not occur repeatedly, my filter works well except it adds single reading time as delay. The microcontroller that I'm using has limited sources with no Floating-point Unit. I am looking for alternative filters which are closer to real-time and does not consume much resource.

Comment: Is your implementation already tuned to micro-controller specification? Like [Median Filter Performance Results
](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/tag/median-filter/)

Comment: @LaurentDuval Yes, it is. The only reason why I'm looking for an alternative is one sample delay.

Comment: What kind of CPU is this, and what's your sample data type?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using median filter with not symmetric window. Anyway, the usual method for removing outlayers is the Hampel filter (also there are some similar alternatives). While median filter modifies the whole signal, the Hampel filter tries to modify the outlayers only

Comment: @MarcusMüller 32 bit, 32MHz non-ARM architecture MCU with bare-metal written firmware

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be looking into Hampel filters and other alternatives.

Comment: 32 bit of what sample format? IEEE 754 floating point? 32 bit signed integer?

Comment: also, could you explain what you mean with "more real-time", because, honestly, comparing 3 numbers for a median should take at most microseconds, and your signals of interest are below 1 Hz, so it really doesn't need to get any more real time. Really, state the problem you have before asking for a solution.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry if my explanation was not proper. Sample format is 32 bit unsigned integer. I wasn't meant delay caused by computation. As you said, it doesn't even take microsecond. 3 points median filter adds 1 sample as delay since you need a new sample to return previously added one.

Comment: Then, what kind of "realtimeness" are you worried about?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Lets say I got [5 6 7] in my buffer. If I got a new sample valued 8, my buffer will be [6 7 8] and return value of the filter will be 7. As you see, If this new sample doesn't set a new median of to the buffer, it'll cause simply 1 sample delay. As suggested in comments, I simply want to just filter out just outlier values.

Comment: you can't. You always need 2 samples of history, to achieve something similar. How else would you know whether something is an outlier and not just the beginning of a rise? Why is 1 to 2 samples of delay a problem?